# Nginx redirect for one path (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I'd like to host a Wordpress site at `http://example.com/content`.

My main site is a Meteor site at example.com with nginx in front of it.

This is my nginx config file, but `http://example.com/content` is just being redirected to `https://example.com/content` and completely ignoring the `/content` location block. Any idea how to fix this?

```
# HTTP
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html; # root is irrelevant
    index index.html index.htm; # this is also irrelevant

    server_name example.com;

    location /content/ {
        proxy_pass http://123.123.123.123; #wordpress ip
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    # redirect non-SSL to SSL
    location / {
        rewrite     ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `location` block is `/content/` and not `/content` as the question implies. Also, does your secure site use HSTS headers?

Comment: I tried it with /content to and it didn't work either. Really what I want it content/* to go to /* on the wp site

Comment: And I don't know what hsts is. The main site uses https and the wp one doesn't

Comment: [HTTP Strict Transport Security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) is quite popular on `https` sites, and if enabled, it will prevent you from accessing the `http` site.

Comment: but why would the https server affect a route that doesn't send traffic to it?

Comment: my https location block does have this: `add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;`

Comment: ah right... `For example, a server could send a header such that future requests to the domain for the next year (max-age is specified in seconds; 31,536,000 is equal to one non-leap year) use only HTTPS: Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000.`
So this is what's happening for the next 2 years. Does this mean I have to serve the WP site over https?

Comment: If you have existing customers using the `https` site, you will need to serve WP over `https` or from another domain/subdomain. If you can reset the browsers that have accessed your `https` site, then you can turn HSTS off and reset those browsers.

Comment: So we have a lot of existing users. Looks like we'll have to serve WP through `https` then. To do this I'd have to copy the SSL certificate from my main domain over to the WP server since they're both the same domain?

Answer (score 0):

As discussed, the use of `add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;` on `example.com` and the fact that you have a number of existing users, means that hosting anything at `http://example.com` is impractical.

You are using `proxy_pass` to host the WordPress site within a subdirectory on the existing domain, but the WordPress server is actually running on a different site.

The WordPress server does not need and cannot use the SSL certificate for `example.com`. Move the `location /content` block to the secure server:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;
    ...
    location ^~ /content {
        proxy_pass http://123.123.123.123;  #wordpress ip
        proxy_set_header Host               $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding    "";
        proxy_set_header Proxy              "";
    }
}
```

Use the `^~` operator to avoid any ambiguity with the existing configuration. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

The WordPress site on `123.123.123.123` must be configured to run under `https://example.com/content/`, which involves changing the HOME and SITEURL variables. See [this document](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL) for more.

Comment: Thanks. It didn't work for me unfortunately. I stuck up a WP site on AWS and DigitalOcean. The DigitalOcean one just gives me an Apache Internal Server Error when I navigate to the page /content. And the AWS one loads the initial page, but none of the assets load properly with a lot of 404 error messages in the console. Any ideas?